# Debug from interactive window in Visual Studio (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, interactive

(Visual Studio Professional 2022, Version 17.4.3)

I'd like to debug a python function called from an interactive window. That is, I'd like to be able to use the interactive window as my main workflow tool, and occasionally "step into" my function calls by setting breakpoints in the source code. In other words, always work in "interactive debug mode".

How can I configure VS to allow for this?